# Using psycopg2 to query postgresql for a decryption but I am getting a memory location, why could this be?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, encryption, psycopg2

I am new to psycopg2 and postgresql (and frankly coding) so I apologize if I have anything wrong to begin with.

I am hoping to create a python script that when prompted by the user for an ID number, it finds the associated encrypted number in the database and then decrypts it and sends it back.

I haven't been able to get my script to output the decrypted number and get what seems to be where it is located in the memory.

Here is my code and result.

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect(database="db_name", user="db_user", password="db_pswrd", host="db_IP")
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> id = input("Enter an id: ")
    Enter an id: 123456
>>> id= str(id)
>>> cur.execute("SELECT id, decrypt(num, 'decryption_key', 'decryption_type') from table_name where id in (%s) ", (id,))

>>> for record in cur:
         print(record)


(123456, <memory at 0x02483590>)
```

The number entered as the id must be a string and the encrypted is type bytea if that is relevant at all.

When I use the part in the `cur.execute` it works just fine in PGAdmin so I am not sure where I could be going wrong.

Please let me know if there is anything else I need to include, I changed some sensitive information.

I am using python 3.4 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

`decrypt` returns `bytea`. As you are printing the row not the individual values, it is not adapted back. Print the values in instead:

```
for r in cur:
    print(r[0], r[1])
```

Tested in Python 2.7:

```
query = "select decrypt(encrypt('1', 'xyz', 'aes'), 'xyz', 'aes');"
cursor.execute(query)
rs = cursor.fetchall()
for r in rs:
    print r, r[0]
```

Output:

```
(<read-only buffer for 0xb732b0e0, size 1, offset 0 at 0xb67a9ca0>,) 1
```

Comment: I made the change you suggested and I am still getting the "memory at..." line :/

Comment: @user5420373 Check my test with Python 2.7

Comment: unfortunately I still cannot get the code to output the decrypted id, I think it is an issue with how the data is stored in our database and using python to execute the query instead of when we manually do it through PGAdmin.  Thank you for your response, I feel better about the work I have done :)